# How to add meta tags on master page dependent on query string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do you add meta tags that change depending on the browser's query string parameter?

For example, on my blog site the blogs are read from a database and a sample blog would be http://www.example.com/blog/blog.aspx?ID=32

I'd like the meta tags to be customized for different blog posts, which all read from the blog.aspx file.

The following posts gives me an idea, but how do I implement a statement to read the query string parameter?

[How to add meta tags on a master page for ASP.Net MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846810/how-to-add-meta-tags-on-a-master-page-for-asp-net-mvc-2)

[How to pass page's meta tags in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144088/how-to-pass-pages-meta-tags-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Please update tag from MVC to either "asp.net-mvc" or "WebForms" depending on what you are using/want to have answer for. Also please clarify if when you say "GET variable" you mean "query string parameter".

Comment: @sapresblue, does my answer helped you in solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Typically in this scenario, I'd have a *base class* for all view models, e.g:

```
public abstract BasicViewModel
{
    public List<string> MetaTags {get; set; }
}
```

Now, if we assume that every view model across our site inherits from this view model, then we can have a strongly typed view model in our layout.

```
@model BasicViewModel
<html>
    <head>
       <!-- Render meta tags here from view model -->
    </head>
    @RenderBody()
</html>
```

I've omitted the fact that a Meta tag may be more intricate than a string, but you get the idea.

In your controllers, provided that *their* view models derive from this - you are free to add any meta tags you wish to the view model.  This also goes towards page titles and anything else common to every page (Google Analytic account details, for example!).

Answer (score 0):

To get dynamic meta keywords and description, here goes my solution using Action Filter.

Create a Action filter and handle its `OnActionExecuted` method -

```
public class MetaDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var key = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

        // using key get proper keywords and description for page

        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.MetaKeywords = "1, 2, 3";
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.MetaDescription = "This is new description";
    }
}
```

Then mark your controller action with the metadata attribute -

```
    [MetaData]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If `id` is the dynamic querystring which you are expecting to the action, then at the end of action execution when OnActionExecuted is called, id will be accessed in the Action filter using RouteData.

Say for example, of you reach the URL - `http://localhost:5738/Blog/Index/123`, then id will be accessed in the Action Filter in this way -

[image]

Then based on the id value, you can set the proper keywords and description in the ViewBag. Then from the Viewbag, you can get the values in the `_Layout.cshtml` as shown below -

```
<meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.MetaKeywords">
<meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription"/>
```

As a result, when page is rendered your meta keywords and description will be reflected as below -

```
<meta name="keywords" content="1, 2, 3">
<meta name="description" content="This is new description"/>
```